# C++ getline() reading in line of file infinitely loops through file

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, getline, printf

I'm trying to read in a line of the file, print out parts of the line, and repeat the process for the next line of the file.

but it doesn't work properly, when I push the output to cmd line it becomes apparent that the while loop is never exitting.

I also tried the same process just using getline() instead, but I have the same problem, it just reads and re-reads the file infinitely.

Here is my code:

```
fstream scores;
scores.open("scores.txt");
string playerName;
string playerScore;
int i = 0;

while (scores >> playerName >> playerScore && i < 8) {
    int line = i * 40;
    int rank = i + 1;

    // testing
    cout << rank << " " << playerName << " " << playerScore << "\n";

    char plRank[1];
    sprintf(plRank, "%i", (rank));
    char plName[8];
    sprintf(plName, "%s", "Name");
    char plScore[8];
    sprintf(plScore, "%s", "score");

    DrawScreenString(GAX1 + 20, GAY1 + 120 + line, plRank, 0x505050, pBody);
    DrawScreenString(GAX1 + 320, GAY1 + 120 + line, plName, 0x505050, pBody);
    DrawScreenString(GAX1 + 570, GAY1 + 120 + line, plScore, 0x505050, pBody);
    i++;
}
scores.close();
```

Here is an extract from the cmd line output.

```
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
1 Edward 100
2 Jodi 80
3 Tom 50
4 Emma 40
...
```

this is what the scores.txt file cotains

```
Edward 100
Jodi 80
Tom 50
Emma 40
```

Any suggestions of why it infinitely loops or fixes would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also tried with `if(!std::string::getline(scores,line)) break;`??

Comment: you might need to test for eof

Comment: Have you tried: while ((scores >> playerName >> playerScore) && i < 8)

Comment: @user2672165 i do not think that would cause a problem. `>>` are operated first then `<` then `&`. there is no other order that would be logical.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ wouldn't that skip lines though?

Comment: `plRank` is too small (it is atleast `char+'\0'`), it could be, that it's corrupting the stack and that is why you get infinite loop.

Comment: @LoganMurphy I meant instead of reading with `while (scores >> playerName >> playerScore && i < 8) {` not just adding the `if` statement inside the while. Sorry, that was a bit misleading ...

Comment: @LoganMurphy I don't see where he should test for `eof`.  While there are arguments why he should read using `getline`, then parse the line, the only thing wrong with his code is that the buffer for one of the `sprintf` is too small (unless there is something really strange going on in `DrawScreenString`).

Comment: I removed plRank and did that bit a different way but the same infinite read and re-read of the file still occurrs..

Comment: @Logan Murphy: Ok. It was just something I would try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tried the same process just using getline() instead, but I have
>   the same problem, it just reads and re-reads the file infinitely.

You should have shown us the `std::getline` code which doesn't work. Using `std::getline` is certainly the preferred solution here. Did you, by any chance, use the member function instead of the free-standing function which works with `std::string`? `sprintf` and arrays are the wrong tools for this task.

Here's what you should do:

1. Read whole lines with the free-standing `std::getline` function.
2. Use `std::getline`'s returned `std::ifstream` itself in the loop condition (it will work due to operator overloading).
3. Tokenize each line *after* reading it. Did you consider what would happen in your program if a player has two first names? Shouldn't this at least result in a meaningful error message?
4. Use `std::string`'s `c_str` member function to safely pass strings to `DrawScreenString`.

Example:

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(scores, line) && (i < 8))
{
    std::vector<std::string> const tokens = tokenize(line);
    // ...

    DrawScreenString(GAX1 + 20, GAY1 + 120 + line, tokens[0].c_str(), 0x505050, pBody);
    // and so on
}
```

The remaining interesting question is how to write the `tokenize` function:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(std::string const &line)
{
    // ?
}
```

Perhaps [Boost Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/tokenizer/) can help you. But you could also just use `std::string`'s member functions like `find` and `substr`.

Just to give you an idea:

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenize(std::string const &line)
{
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    std::string::size_type const pos_first_space = line.find(" ");
    if (pos_first_space == std::string::npos)
    {
        // error, no space found
    }
    std::string const first_token = line.substr(0, pos_first_space);
    result.push_back(first_token);

    // ...

    return result;
}
```

The point is: **separate** reading a line from tokenizing a line.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I'll give this a go. Sorry I din't explain, the current use of sprintf is completely unnecessary, I plan to make use of them later once I had ironed out the infinite re-reading of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work quite well. You can easily modify it for your other purposes and/or use different means for output. I have also made slight modifications, note:

I recommend not using stream.open(), but rather a constructor as shown.
The stream is closed implicitly, no need for stream.close()

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// reads name, score entries from text file

int main()
{
    std::ifstream scores("scores.txt");
    std::string line {""};
    int lineNr {1};
    while(std::getline(scores, line))
    {
        std::stringstream stream(line);
        std::string name;
        int score;
        if(stream >> name >> score)
            std::cout << lineNr << ' ' << name << ' ' << score << '\n';

        else
            std::cerr << "Error: invalid score entry in line " << lineNr << ".\n";

        ++lineNr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks: I tried implementing your code, but I get the same issue, It just reads and re-reads the file continuously..

Comment: I used a textfile "scores.txt" with the content `Edward 100
Jodi 80
Tom 50
Emma 40
fail err
corrupt line
Adam 20` and I cannot reproduce your error. Did you use _exactely_ the same code, or combine it with other things?

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code, did your file have a new line after each player and their respective score?

Comment: Yes, it does. Which things have you tried outputting for debug information? E.g. try outputting the lineNr and maybe line each time around the loop or so...

Comment: lineNr output's as expected, everything outputs as you expect until it reads to the bottom of the file, and then rather than stopping it just rereads the file

Comment: If you really used exactely this code with nothing else and still get the "reading over and over" error, I cannot help you. My knowledge ends here. Maybe some problem with the streamstate or line-endings, I don't know...

Comment: ok, thank-you very much for your help, I'll keep working at it

Comment: Looking back at this code, it is bad  because it doesn't check for he file actually being opened: "if (!scores) { */ error */ }